# Position of the first line on UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

I have 2 UILabels, one which is multi-line and other is of 2 lines. I always have an image besides these labels and its becoming difficult for me to align the image with the text. Eg:

If the 2 line label just has some small text on it, the text is displayed on the middle of the label and the image is aligned with the first line. If it has exactly 2 lines on text on it, then the image is aligned to the first line of text which is exactly what I want.

Is there a way I can get the position or co-ordinates (x,y) of the first line on UILabel so that I can adjust the image constraints accordingly then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the co-ordinates and the dimensions:

```
label.frame.origin.x
label.frame.origin.y
label.frame.size.width
label.frame.size.height
```